# Which software sequencers are good for live performances?

Tags: midi, live-performance

I'm looking for software sequencer that is designed to be helpful in live performances. Almost every software sequencers I know is rather a MIDI note-sheet editor, which forces it's users to use it offline only.

Could you please recommend me a piece of software that aims for **live** sequencing? Preferably MIDI, but any other protocol too.

Comment: I've performed once with Reaper, even though it's a note-sheet kind of editor. They can be used for live work (play back recorded material plus change parameters live), which is somewhat limited, but certainly doesn't force only offline use :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try [Ableton Live](http://www.ableton.com/live-8).  I have heard of many people using it for live performances.  It can play back MIDI and recorded audio, does looping and many other things, so it should meet your needs.

If you are on a budget, you could try [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/index.php).

Both programs have a free trial, so you can try them both and see which better fits your needs and style.

Comment: I use Ableton Live with some VSTs almost exclusively. On occasion, I will use Reason with it.

Comment: Ableton Live is pretty much the only sequencer with real "Live" features.

Answer (score 1):

[Renoise](http://renoise.com/) is great for live performances.  Be sure to also check out the [Duplex](http://tools.renoise.com/tools/duplex) plugin which provides automatic MIDI/OSC controller mappings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are into live algorithmic composition, you might also be interested in the [free IMPROVISOR software by Percussa](https://www.percussa.com/audiocubes-improvisor) which works with the Percussa AudioCubes as well as [Ableton Live](http://www.ableton.com/).

Answer (score 0):

+1 on renoise, especially when you equip it with 'tools' (kind of legacy utility plugins you can get from their website).
Most popular live solution would be Ableton Live, but also Bitwig Studio gives you very similliar functionality, philosophy and workflow with just a bit different flavour.
But nowadays even FL Studio has a live mode...

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend ModStep for ipad. Which is purely a midi sequencer (no audio recording or anything) but it has lots of hands-on performance controls. And I believe all of its functions are usable without stopping the sequence, so it is especially made for live.

There are still minor features that I wish would be implemented, but it is already a quality product.

Answer (score 0):

For all musicians that need to play backtracks on stage I strongly suggest Livetraker. Check the video demo:

This is a powerful piece of software, but very easy to use. It was created by a coder that is also a musician.

The software manages audio, midi and text too, in a fast way because it is designed for live performance on stage (IMHO: few buttons, stability and speed...).

There is a trial version available for Windows and Mac at their official website https://livetraker.com/